# Ubuntu: User 'uname' is not allowed to use [tool]

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, incron

I found this cool tool called "incron."  I think it will be a great productivity booster, but I am having issues getting it to run.

```
sudo apt-get install incron
...
Adding group `incron'
...
sudo usermod -a -G incron myname # no luck
```

```
incrontab -e # user 'myname' is not allowed to use incron
```

---

This seems to be a pretty cut and dry problem -- I should be able to get it to "just work"; however, it is not.  Is there an easy way to get this running?

Comment: Try to re-login to your session.

Comment: @annahri I should state that I am on `wsl-2` (windows subsystem for linux 2).  This is a dockerized ubuntu... perhaps there is something there?

Comment: I'll try rebooting when I get a chance

Comment: You don't need to reboot. Simply log out and log in. Then all your processes will have `incron` group membership,  or (after reading `man newgrp`), `newgrp incron` and try `incrontab -e` again..

Comment: @waltinator thanks, yeah, reading the docs is something I'm doing now, but would not have known which doc to read.